# Ассемблер NASM. Ошибка: unable to open include file `stud_io.inc'

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Изучаю книгу "Программирование. Введение в профессию" Столярова, второй том.
Пишу мою первую программу на ассемблере:

```
%include "stud_io.inc"
global _start

section .text
_start: mov eax, 0
again: PRINT "Hello"
PUTCHAR 10
inc eax
cmp eax, 5
jl again
FINISH
```

Пишу в консоли: `nasm -f elf hello5.asm`, компилятор пишет:

```
hello5.asm:1: error: unable to open include file `stud_io.inc': No such file or directory
hello5.asm:6: error: parser: instruction expected
hello5.asm:7: error: parser: instruction expected
hello5.asm:11: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
```

Comment: Ну а файл этот есть?

Comment: @dIm0n ну да, есть. Его текст я представил.

Comment: Я про файл `stud_io.inc`

Comment: @dIm0n не знаю. Я не знаю, где его искать.

Comment: [В той же директории](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18077152/13970074)

Comment: @dIm0n к этой книге прилагается архив файлов, и там, как раз, и есть этот `stud_io.inc`. Я думал, что он изначально есть в какой-нибудь библиотеке у ассемблера. Главное - в книге об этом ни слова! Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы можете добавить ответ на собственный вопрос, чтобы он не простаивал без ответа

Comment: @dIm0n могу, но вопрос какой-то специфичный и по сути связан только с книгой. На вопрос, как подключить дополнительные файлы (модули?), ответы в интернете уже есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой, для решения тебе нужно скачать файл с макросами с официального сайта [Андрея Викторовича Столярова](http://stolyarov.info/books/asm_unix).

На этой странице скачай нужный тебе файл, размести его рядом с твоим файлом *.asm, запуск компилятора будет следуюший:

**nasm -f file.asm**

Альтернативно, можешь завести у себя в корне проекта папку с макросами и в нее разместить данный файл, при этом запуск компилятора будет выглядеть так:

****nasm -i "/путь_до_папки_с_макросами" -f elf file.asm****

Comment: Ну да, собственно, в комментариях я уже написал, что к книге прилагался архив файлов)
Ну ладно. Хороший ответ всё-равно.